# Receiving "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict"

Tags: python, json, tweepy

I have a json output from Tweepy, which I'm now trying to parse through. For instance, some of the output are trending hashtags for a particular area. Since it is a large output, I'm trying to determine how to efficiently parse through all of the hashtags. There is other information in the json output such as `userid`, `countrycode`, etc... But I'm only interested in the hashtags which are listed as `name: '#gamenight` for instance.

```
# using Tweepy

api.trends_place(2295420)

import json 

# Here is a portion of the Tweepy output I received
trends = [{'trends': [{'name': '#RCBvKKR', 'url': 'http://twitter.com/search?q=%23RCBvKKR', 'promoted_content': None, 'query': '%23RCBvKKR', 'tweet_volume': 101508}, {'name': 'created_at': '2019-04-06T00:07:14Z', 'locations': [{'name': 'Bangalore', 'woeid': 2295420}]}]

hashtags = json.dumps(trends)

# Am trying to end up with a way of just extracting 'name' which I believe is how the hashtags are captured 

print(hashtags['name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `hastags["trends"][0]["name"]` to receive `#RCBvKKR`

---

Okay I fixed it. First, the posted code is confusing. The json you posted is not valid, (brackets are missing and name key has no value). Second , with your command `json.dumps(trends)`, You are converting already valid python dictionary to a string, which is an array, thus the error, (`string indices must be integers`)

The fixed version is like this:

```
import json

trends = [{'trends': [{'name': '#RCBvKKR', 'url': 'http://twitter.com/search?q=%23RCBvKKR', 'promoted_content': None, 'query': '%23RCBvKKR', 'tweet_volume': 101508}, {'name':"This was missing", 'created_at': '2019-04-06T00:07:14Z', 'locations': [{'name': 'Bangalore', 'woeid': 2295420}]}]}]


print(trends[0]["trends"][0]["name"])
```

Now the output is `#RCBvKKR`

If you indeed receive a json string from the API, use `json.parse(response)` to convert string to python dict.

Comment: I received another error TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @Tweep , yep I fixed it

Comment: I think i mislabeled the Tweepy output I received as JSON, without really knowing if it was or not. I'm still trying to identify what format Tweepy output for api.trends_place comes in as. i.e. is it an array, hash, json?

Comment: I'm also trying to retrieve every instance of 'name' not just '#RCBvKRR'